# Split data.frame based on condition

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following data.frame, where pos is a position coordinate. I've included a variable thresh where val is greater than a given threshold t.

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 20
t <- 0
DF <- data.frame(pos = seq(from = 0, by = 0.3, length.out = n),
                 val = sample(-2:5, size = n, replace = TRUE))
DF$thresh <- DF$val > t
DF

##    pos val thresh
## 1  0.0   0  FALSE
## 2  0.3   4   TRUE
## 3  0.6   1   TRUE
## 4  0.9   5   TRUE
## 5  1.2   5   TRUE
## 6  1.5  -2  FALSE
## 7  1.8   2   TRUE
## 8  2.1   5   TRUE
## 9  2.4   2   TRUE
## 10 2.7   1   TRUE
## 11 3.0   5   TRUE
## 12 3.3   1   TRUE
## 13 3.6   3   TRUE
## 14 3.9   2   TRUE
## 15 4.2  -2  FALSE
## 16 4.5   5   TRUE
## 17 4.8  -1  FALSE
## 18 5.1  -2  FALSE
## 19 5.4   0  FALSE
## 20 5.7   5   TRUE
```

How could I get region coordinates where val is positive i.e. in the above example:

```
0.3 - 1.2,
1.8 - 3.9,
4.5 - 4.5,
5.7 - 5.7
```

I have thought of splitting the data.frame by thresh and then accessing pos from the first and last row of each data.frame list element, but that will just combine all the TRUE and FALSE subsets together. Is there a way to convert the thresh variable into a character based on the TRUE value, and discarding the FALSE values?

```
split(DF, DF$thresh) # not what I want


## $`FALSE`
##    pos val thresh
## 1  0.0   0  FALSE
## 6  1.5  -2  FALSE
## 15 4.2  -2  FALSE
## 17 4.8  -1  FALSE
## 18 5.1  -2  FALSE
## 19 5.4   0  FALSE
## 
## $`TRUE`
##    pos val thresh
## 2  0.3   4   TRUE
## 3  0.6   1   TRUE
## 4  0.9   5   TRUE
## 5  1.2   5   TRUE
## 7  1.8   2   TRUE
## 8  2.1   5   TRUE
## 9  2.4   2   TRUE
## 10 2.7   1   TRUE
## 11 3.0   5   TRUE
## 12 3.3   1   TRUE
## 13 3.6   3   TRUE
## 14 3.9   2   TRUE
## 16 4.5   5   TRUE
## 20 5.7   5   TRUE
```

Another clunky thing I tried was `cumsum` but again it includes false rows:

```
split(DF, cumsum(DF$thresh == 0)) # not what I want but close to it...


## $`1`
##   pos val thresh
## 1 0.0   0  FALSE
## 2 0.3   4   TRUE
## 3 0.6   1   TRUE
## 4 0.9   5   TRUE
## 5 1.2   5   TRUE
## 
## $`2`
##    pos val thresh
## 6  1.5  -2  FALSE
## 7  1.8   2   TRUE
## 8  2.1   5   TRUE
## 9  2.4   2   TRUE
## 10 2.7   1   TRUE
## 11 3.0   5   TRUE
## 12 3.3   1   TRUE
## 13 3.6   3   TRUE
## 14 3.9   2   TRUE
## 
## $`3`
##    pos val thresh
## 15 4.2  -2  FALSE
## 16 4.5   5   TRUE
## 
## $`4`
##    pos val thresh
## 17 4.8  -1  FALSE
## 
## $`5`
##    pos val thresh
## 18 5.1  -2  FALSE
## 
## $`6`
##    pos val thresh
## 19 5.4   0  FALSE
## 20 5.7   5   TRUE
```

Comment: Don't see any issue with the split command. Anyway, instead of split, why not just go with `DF[DF$thresh==T, ]`?

Comment: @AdamQuek because that will give all the TRUE rows together combined, but I want to access the exact 'regions'. Going your way would give me limits of 0.3 - 5.7...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one option with `data.table`.  We create a grouping variable using `rleid`, subset the 'pos' based on 'thresh' and `split`.

```
DT <- setDT(DF)[,pos[thresh] ,.(gr=rleid(thresh))]
split(DT$V1, DT$gr)
#$`2`
#[1] 0.3 0.6 0.9 1.2

#$`4`
#[1] 1.8 2.1 2.4 2.7 3.0 3.3 3.6 3.9

#$`6`
#[1] 4.5

#$`8`
#[1] 5.7
```

---

Or we can use `rle` from `base R` to create the grouping variable and then `split` based on that

```
gr <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(DF$thresh), values <- seq_along(values)))
with(DF, split(pos[thresh], gr[thresh]))
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned, `cumsum` can also be used for grouping after subsetting using the 'thresh'.

```
 with(DF, split(pos[thresh],cumsum(!thresh)[thresh]))
```

Comment: Alternative - `split(DF$pos[DF$thresh],cumsum(!DF$thresh)[DF$thresh])`